# How do I find the value of this missing variable and the normal to the equation?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How do I find the value of this missing variable and the normal to the equation?

The line $y = 4x + k$ is a tangent to $y = x^2 + 4x + 3$, at point $P$.

1) Find the value of $k$.

2) Find the equation of the normal to the curve $y = x^2 + 4x + 3$, at point $P$.

Answer (score 2):

The line that is tangent to $y=x^2+4x+3$ at a point has the slope of that curve at the point.  The slope is the derivative of the curve at that point, where you have
$$
y' = 2x+4
$$
Since you know the line $4x+k$ is tangent, and the slope of this line is $4$, you are looking for where the slope $y'=4$ or
$$
2x+4 = 4
$$
which is true for 
$$ x=0 $$
Since the line is tangent to $x^2+4x+3$, you also know the $y$ value at $x=0$ is given by
$$
y = 0^2+4(0)+3 = 3
$$
so the point where the line is tangent is $$ P = (0,3) $$
We also can see the value of $k$ must be $3$ so that $y=4x+k$ is $3$ at $x=0$.

Now to find the perpendicular to the tangent...

A perpendicular line has opposite inverse slope and this one goes through the point $P=(0,3)$, so we can write
$$
y-3 = \left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)(x-0)
$$